# How add the event of mouse over in a ListBox on Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
private ListBox linkList = new ListBox();
```

here I want to add the event of mouseOver for each item from the linkList

I tried:

```
foreach(ListItem item in linkList.Items){
    ...
}
```

but didn't work
what can I do?

this is how the ListBox is filling :

```
<ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Links}"  
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="50" Background="Transparent" Width="500">
                <Border Padding="10">
                    <Path x:Name="icon" Data="{Binding IconData}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock x:Name="texto" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"  Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="45,2,2,2" FontSize="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IconData}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="texto">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Thickness Bottom="2" Top="2" Left="10" Right="2"/> 
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="icon">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#f2f2f2" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>

            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Update:

Code Behind:

```
public partial class ModernVerticalMenu
    : Control
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the ContentLoader dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentLoaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentLoader", typeof(IContentLoader), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(new DefaultContentLoader()));
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Layout dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LayoutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Layout", typeof(TabLayout), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(TabLayout.Tab));
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the ListWidth dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ListWidth", typeof(GridLength), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(170)));
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the Links dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LinksProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Links", typeof(LinkCollection), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(OnLinksChanged));
    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the SelectedSource dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedSource", typeof(Uri), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedSourceChanged));
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the SelectedLinkGroup dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLinkGroupProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLinkGroup", typeof(LinkCollection), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedLinkGroupChanged));
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the SelectedLink dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLinkProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLink", typeof(Link), typeof(ModernVerticalMenu), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedLinkChanged));


    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the selected source has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<SourceEventArgs> SelectedSourceChanged;

    private ListBox linkList;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ModernVerticalMenu"/> control.
    /// </summary>
    public ModernVerticalMenu()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ModernVerticalMenu);

        // create a default links collection
        SetCurrentValue(LinksProperty, new LinkCollection());
    }

    private static void OnSelectedLinkGroupChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // retrieve the selected link from the group
        var group = (Link)e.NewValue; // cria uma nova instancia do grupo
        Link selectedLink = null; //cria um link selecionado
        if (group != null)
        { //se o grupo copiado existe
            selectedLink = group; //

            // if no link selected or link doesn't exist in group links, auto-select first
            if (group.Children != null)
            {
                if (selectedLink != null && !group.Children.Any(l => l == selectedLink))
                {
                    selectedLink = null;
                }

                if (selectedLink == null)
                {
                    selectedLink = group.Children.FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }

        // update the selected link
        ((ModernVerticalMenu)o).SetCurrentValue(SelectedLinkProperty, selectedLink);
    }

    private static void OnSelectedLinkChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // update selected source
        var newValue = (Link)e.NewValue;
        Uri selectedSource = null;
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            selectedSource = newValue.Source;
        }
        ((ModernVerticalMenu)o).SetCurrentValue(SelectedSourceProperty, selectedSource);
    }


    private static void OnLinksChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ModernVerticalMenu)o).UpdateSelection();
    }

    private static void OnSelectedSourceChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ModernVerticalMenu)o).OnSelectedSourceChanged((Uri)e.OldValue, (Uri)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnSelectedSourceChanged(Uri oldValue, Uri newValue)
    {
        UpdateSelection();

        // raise SelectedSourceChanged event
        var handler = this.SelectedSourceChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new SourceEventArgs(newValue));
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSelection()
    {
        if (this.linkList == null || this.Links == null) {
            return;
        }

        // sync list selection with current source

        this.linkList.SelectedItem = this.Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Source == this.SelectedSource);
        SetValue(SelectedLinkGroupProperty, this.Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Children == this.SelectedLinkGroup));
        if (this.Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Children == this.SelectedLinkGroup) != null)
            MessageBox.Show(this.Links.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Children == this.SelectedLinkGroup).Children.Count.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When overridden in a derived class, is invoked whenever application code or internal processes call System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate().
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (this.linkList != null) {
            this.linkList.SelectionChanged -= OnLinkListSelectionChanged;
        }

        this.linkList = GetTemplateChild("LinkList") as ListBox;
        if (this.linkList != null) {
            this.linkList.SelectionChanged += OnLinkListSelectionChanged;
        }

        UpdateSelection();
    }

    private void OnLinkListSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var link = this.linkList.SelectedItem as Link;
        if (link != null && link.Source != this.SelectedSource) {
            SetCurrentValue(SelectedSourceProperty, link.Source);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the content loader.
    /// </summary>
    public IContentLoader ContentLoader
    {
        get { return (IContentLoader)GetValue(ContentLoaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentLoaderProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating how the tab should be rendered.
    /// </summary>
    public TabLayout Layout
    {
        get { return (TabLayout)GetValue(LayoutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LayoutProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of links that define the available content in this tab.
    /// </summary>
    public LinkCollection Links
    {
        get { return (LinkCollection)GetValue(LinksProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LinksProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of links that define the available content in this tab.
    /// </summary>
    public LinkCollection SelectedLinkGroup
    {
        get { return (LinkCollection)GetValue(SelectedLinkGroupProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedLinkGroupProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of links that define the available content in this tab.
    /// </summary>
    public Link SelectedLink
    {
        get { return (Link)GetValue(SelectedLinkProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedLinkProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the width of the list when Layout is set to List.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The width of the list.
    /// </value>
    public GridLength ListWidth
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(ListWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the source URI of the selected link.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The source URI of the selected link.</value>
    public Uri SelectedSource
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(SelectedSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

this causes compilation's errors because of the conflict of base classes(ResourceDictionary and Control)

All XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls" x:Class="FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls.ModernVerticalMenu">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/Converters.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style TargetType="controls:ModernVerticalMenu" >
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:ModernVerticalMenu">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding ListWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="{TemplateBinding ListWidth}"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding BackColor}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource bordaSuperior}">
                        <!-- link list -->
                        <ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ItemsSource="{Binding Links, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  
                                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" >

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Height="50" Background="Transparent" Width="500">
                                        <Border Name="border" Padding="10">
                                            <Path x:Name="icon" Data="{Binding IconData}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="texto" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"  Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="45,2,2,2" FontSize="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IconData}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="texto">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <Thickness Bottom="2" Top="2" Left="10" Right="2"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Trigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="controls:ModernVerticalMenu.BackColor" Value="Red"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="icon">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#f2f2f2" />
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Trigger.Setters>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Border>

                    <Border x:Name="submenu" Grid.Column="1" Background="{DynamicResource background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource bordaSuperior}">
                        <!-- link list -->

                        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLinkGroup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" >

                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Height="50" Background="Transparent" Width="500">
                                        <Border Padding="10">
                                            <Path x:Name="icon" Data="{Binding IconData}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource Accent}" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="texto" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}"  Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="45,2,2,2" FontSize="{DynamicResource MediumFontSize}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                                    </Grid>
                                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IconData}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="texto">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <Thickness Bottom="2" Top="2" Left="10" Right="2"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>

                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="icon">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#f2f2f2" />
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <!--{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=controls:ModernVerticalMenu}, Path=SelectedLinkGroup}-->
                                            <Setter Property="controls:ModernVerticalMenu.SelectedLinkGroup" Value="{Binding Children}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListBox>
                    </Border>

                    <controls:ModernFrame Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding SelectedSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" ContentLoader="{TemplateBinding ContentLoader}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedLinkGroup.Count,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="submenu" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: what/how didn't it work? what happened? what code is in the '...'?

Comment: (var item in linkList.Items)<-- here I have a CastException

Comment: when I change the var by ListItem I put wrong sorry

Comment: It's a listboxitem and not a ListItem!

Comment: listboxitem give the same exception

Comment: can you write the exception here? I suppose that you have elements in the listbox!

Comment: InvalidCastException, sim eu tenho

Comment: What are the items inside the Listbox?

Comment: what you want to perform on mouse over? animate etc? I believe there is an easier way to do that too.

Comment: `linkList` is not the same as `LinkList`. They will be two different lists, `LinkList` will probably be created via `InitializeComponent` from the views constructor. Can you add the code where you populate `linkList`, i.e. the list which you are trying to enumerate?

Comment: <mui:Link DisplayName="Clientes"  />

<mui:Link  DisplayName="Agendamentos" />

<mui:Link DisplayName="Ordem de serviço"  />

<mui:Link  DisplayName="Problemas" />



this is what have in the ListBox

Comment: e o que queres fazer ao certo mesmo?

Comment: O listbox tem itens que são links e quero adiconar em cada item o evento de mouseOver

Comment: mas para que fim? para ver qual a melhor alternativa...

Comment: é que quando eu clico em um item abre um novo ListBox ao lado e eu quero fazer aparecer esse outro listbox só em passar o mouse pelo item, é tipo um menu lateral com subitens

Comment: Isso não vai ser tarefa fácil. Mas é melhor "jogar" com o Visibility e IsMouseOver

Comment: @Rafael What do you actually need to achieve in the event handler (maybe it can be done differently)? Can you provide all the XAML code as well? What is the reason for having both a listbox in code behind and in the XAML?

Comment: I updated with all xaml now, because I need know what is the item selected in the listbox, to can alter the other properties from the class

Answer (score 1):

ListBox.Items does not actually contain ListBoxItems, but the underlying object which is being displayed by the ListBoxItem. This is how to get the ListBoxItem:

```
foreach(var item in linkList.Items)
{
    var container = (ListBoxItem)linkList.ItemsContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
}
```

EDIT:

However, as pushpraj points out, the ListBox is by default virtualized, which means the only the visible items will have a ListBoxItem. Furthermore, once they are scrolled out of view, they are dropped. Therefore attaching an event handler to the ListBoxItem from outside is quite risky because you can easily leak event handlers as ListBoxItems are created and dropped when scrolling.

UPDATE:

Since you specify you own item template you can also just hook up a MouseEnter event on the grid:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LinkList" ... >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterItem" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Width="500" >
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: it may fail with virtualization (default on) when the item is not in the view.

Comment: don't have the MouseOver in the Grid

Comment: and what is the OnMouseOverItem?

Comment: @Rafael The event is actually MouseEnter, I have corrected the answer. The OnMouseOverItem is just the event handler method in the code-behind.

Comment: but this wpf code is on the Resource Dictionary and the code behind class extends from Control.I need to parse the class to partial and this give me some compilations erros, i will put an update with the code behind